# Replacing Backslashes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I convert the following string from

```
var x = "F:\RSSIMS\database\"
```

to:

```
var x = "F:\\RRSIMS\\database\\"
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Did you do any research whatsoever? Any googling? Any documentation lookups? Any test code? Any partially working test code? Anything?

Comment: Your first string won't have any backslashes, and isn't actually valid code. Are you saying that you have a string with actual backslashes, and you need double backslashes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var x = "F:\RSSIMS\database\"` is **already invalid**. You need to escape your backslashes.

```
var x = "F:\\RSSIMS\\database\\";//stores the string `F:\RSSIMS\database\` in x.
```

If you want double-slashes now, do **the below** to replace all the single slashes by double ones.

```
x = x.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
```